# docker-compose invalid type port value when reading from .env file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

**Issue**
When I try to run `docker-compose exec app "something"` I get the following error:

```
ERROR: The Compose file './../docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.phpmyadmin.ports contains an invalid type, it should be a number, or an object
services.db.ports contains an invalid type, it should be a number, or an object
services.web.ports contains an invalid type, it should be a number, or an object
```

**Bad Solution**
I solved the issue by changing the places with the following code:

```
ports:
      - ${IP}:80:80 
      //or other ports such as :3306
```

I removed `${IP}` and added the port directly (127.0.0.5).

**Question**
However the IP variable is set inside the .env file, so I do not see why this pops up.
I also have another project with exact same docker-compose and .env files that is running without issues, so why is this happening?

Comment: I dont think you can add an IP in the ports section. It is only for port mapping. Thus 80:80

Comment: It works in the other project tho, and ```127.0.0.5:80:80``` is working fine as well.

Comment: @ivoba You are allowed to include an IP address there; it is the host IP Docker binds the published port to, defaults to 0.0.0.0 (all interfaces).  The most common use case is binding a port to `127.0.0.1:12345:6789` to make it only accessible from the host, less common is using it to bind to a specific interface on a multi-network server.